# compare two set is the same in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

How can I fix the type in typescript to compare two set is the same? I want to compare the all text of element that get from cypress are the same as values. But I hit the error with `Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.` How can I fix it?

```
import cypress
const values = [1,2,3]
let rtn = new Set();
let inputValues = new Set(values);
cy.get('selector')
  .each((element) => {
    rtn.add(element.text());
  });
cy.should('be.true', rtn.size === inputValues.size && [...rtn].every((value) => inputValues.has(value)));
```

Comment: did you try  cy.get('selector').each( element:any)??

Comment: yap...it does not work.